# WPF action befor exit

Tags: c#, wpf, exit

On wpf I want to know when the user press on `X` to exit.

Then I want to do some functions.

How can I do it on wpf c#?

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closing += (sender, args) => ...; // Occurs after X is pressed. You can cancel closure here.
        this.Closed += (sender, args) => ...; // Occurs when the window is already closed.
    }
}
```